# numberOfRowsInSection causing crash in swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I'm trying to build a uitableviewcontroller and am having difficulty dealing with swift 3. Whenever the numberOfRowsInSection gets called, it gets called 4 times and then the app crashes. Does anyone know how to implement this is swift 3?

```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6;

}
```

There are 6 items in the array that I want to populate the table with. I printed the array count to confirm. this is the full view controller.

```
class PCRInpatientsViewController: UITableViewController
{
var listInpatient = [PCRPatient]();

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated);


    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.none;

    self.title = "Inpatients";

    let view = self.view.frame;
    let background = UIView(frame: view);
    background.backgroundColor = Constants.medisasDarkGrey;
    self.tableView.backgroundView = background;

    self.definesPresentationContext = true;

    getPatients();
    createUI();

}

func getPatients() {

    var array = [PCRPatient]();
            let i = Patients.sharedInstance.patients

            for int in 0..<i.count {
                let d = i[int];

                if d.status == PCRPatientStatus.PreAdmit {
                    print(d.name)
                    array.append(d);
                }


            }
    print(array.count);
    self.listInpatient = array;


}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated);

}

func createUI (){


    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Constants.medisasRed;
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false;
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white();
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white()];


}



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 6;

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 150;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> PCRCustomCell {

    let patient = listInpatient[indexPath.row];
    print("sjddsodkso \(patient.name)");

    let cell = PCRCustomCell(reuse: "Inpatient", patient: patient);
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = Constants.medisasGrey;


    return cell;
}

}
```

Comment: I checked and there is 6 items in the array. I added rthe full view controller

Comment: Thats what it originally was, but I changed it to 6 because it was crashing and I wanted to make see if it would crash if I wrote 6. It still crashes though. This would have worked fine in the old swift, which is why I think some change from swift 3 is the cause.

Comment: I suppose I'll defer to someone with more knowledge. I look forward to seeing what the issue was.

Comment: Always validate array before access 1 object of array
`if (listInpatient.count > indexPath.row) ..... // do something`

Comment: Don't hard-code the returned value in `numberOfRowsInSection`, use always `listInpatient.count`. Actually you can write the entire method `getPatients()` in one line: `listInpatient = Patients.sharedInstance.patients.filter {$0.status == .PreAdmit}`. And get rid of the semicolons, they are not needed in Swift.

Comment: PS: and where do you call `reloadData()`?

Answer (score 2):

A couple syntax changes in Swift 3 that you need to incorporate. Xcode 8 beta will often suggest the correct fixes to your code but not always. I wrestled with this before finding out that you can check the updated documentation in Xcode 8 beta by hitting `Shift + Command + 0` and searching for the first few characters of almost anything. In this case, search for `UITableViewDataSource` and you'll see everything I'm about to note.

1) `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is now `cellForRowAt`. `NSIndexPath` is now `IndexPath`. Implement like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // if you use prototype cells
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "prototypeCellIdentifier") as! CustomUITableViewCell

    // configure your cell

    return cell
}
```

2) `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is similarly now `heightForRowAt`. I haven't implemented this personally but but from the docs it's implemented like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return float
}
```

3) As others noted, numberOfRowsInSection should be dynamic, but I don't believe it's causing the crashes.